# Envio de arquivo via CURL usando PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Como traduzir para PHP o seguinte comando CURL?

```
curl -F file=@/home/user/picture.jpg

https://api.dominio.com/pictures
```

Tentei de algumas maneiras mas as que achei eram todas enviando com alguma chave (ex: myfile => /home/user/picture.jpg) mas no caso parece não ter uma chave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No PHP 5.6 e superior você tem o `curl_file_create`, você pode utilizar ele.

```
curl -F file=@/home/user/picture.jpg https://api.dominio.com/pictures
```

Isso indica exatamente:

- `-F` indica que é um `multipart/form-data` e por isso o `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` deve ser passado por `array`.
- O "`file`" indica o nome do parâmetro, *ou seja a "chave"*.
- O "`/home/user/picture.jpg`" indica o caminho do arquivo, o `@` antes dele indica que é para ser lido o arquivo do caminho (*e não enviado `/home/user/picture.jpg` como texto*).

Sabendo disso basta utilizar o CURL do PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.dominio.com/pictures');

curl_setopt_array($ch, [    
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [          
      'file' => curl_file_create('/home/user/picture.jpg')
    ]
]);

$resposta = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

Se estiver em versões antigas o PHP nem tudo está perdido, você pode utilizar:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [          
   'file' => '@/home/user/picture.jpg'
]
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente :)